# MySQL Select rows <= now(), using separated time fields

Tags: mysql, time

I have a table 't' with date(yyyy-mm-dd), hour(1-12), minute(00-59), ampm(a/p), and timezone(pst/est) fields.

How can I select the rows that are <= now()? (ie. already happened)

Thank you for your suggestions!

edit: this does it without attention to the hour/minute/ap/tz fields:

```
SELECT * FROM t.date WHERE date <= now()
```

Comment: Is the schema for this table out of your control? MySQL has a [`datetime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) date type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it - combine all your seconds, minutes, etc into a date and compare to `NOW()`, making sure you do the comparison in the same time-zone. (Untested):

```
SELECT *
FROM t
LEFT JOIN y ON t.constant=y.constant
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date,' ',hour,':',minute,' 'ampm),
                             '%Y-%m-%d %l:%i %p' ),
                 timezone,"SYSTEM") < NOW();
```

If your hour is 01 - 12 not 1-12 then use `%h` instead of `%l` in the `STR_TO_DATE`.

The `STR_TO_DATE` tries to stick your date and time columns together and convert them into a date.

The `CONVERT_TZ(...,timezone,"SYSTEM")` converts this date from whatever timezone is specified in the `timezone` column to system time.

This is then compared to `NOW()`, which is always in system time.

As an aside, perhaps you should make a single column `date` using MySQL's date datatype, as it's a lot easier to do arithmetic on that!

For reference, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) is a summary of very useful mysql date functions where you can read up on those featuring in this answer.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM t
WHERE `date`<=DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
OR (
  `date`<=DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   AND
   CONVERT_TZ(CAST(CONCAT(`date`,' ',IF(`hour`=12 AND ampm='a',0,if(ampm='a',`hour`,`hour`+12)),':',`minute`,':00') AS DATETIME),'GMT',`timezone`)<=NOW()
)
```

Rationale for `date`<=DATE_[ADD|SUB](curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY):

The fancy conversion is quite an expensive operation, so we don't want it to run on the complete table. This is why we pre-select against an UNCHANGED `date` field (possibly using an index). In no timezone can an event being more than a day in current timezone's past be in the future, and in no timezone can an event more than a day in the curent timezone's future be in the past.